# Understanding Error Message

Tags: c#, .net, webapi2

> {   "message": "Foo request failed",   "errors": [
>       "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Boolean'. Path '[43].Group_Is_Full', line 1, position 30730.",
>       "Null object cannot be converted to a value type."   ] }

My goal is to narrow down the exact piece of code in which this error occurred. I cannot step through it easily in prod for a variety of reasons.

So, does `Path '[43] , line 1, position 30730` provide me with anything that can help in that regard (I don't know what any of those numbers refer to and that's my question).

P.S. This is coming from a `.NET C# Web API 2` backend. It's a response to a `POST` request that comes back with a `400`.

Edit:

This is the body of the json being sent, I am looking into it more, stand by for more updates:

```
{
  "contactId": 999999,
  "address": {
    "addressLine1": "9999 Foo ave",
    "addressLine2": null,
    "city": "Phoenix",
    "state": "AZ",
    "zip": "43127"
  },
  "isHomeAddress": true,
  "contactNumber": "513-123-4568",
  "groupDescription": "Lol join this, its awesome"
}
```

Comment: "exact piece of code" so, how about to show some code to us?

Comment: @AleksAndreev the point of the question is he's asking how to identify the problem code from the error message.

Comment: @AleksAndreev What Amy said - I am trying to find where this error is occurring, I can figure out the code myself once I actually find it.

Comment: @VSO You're posting a huge JSON object, at least 30,730 characters.  I expect `[43]` is the 43rd position in an array you're sending.  Inspect your JSON and look at the 43rd element in the array.  It's `Group_Is_Full` property is either null or undefined.    `Path '[43].Group_Is_Full'` is actually the location in the JSON that is causing trouble, not the location in your code.

Comment: Could you show your code that call web API? Maybe something wrong with parameters.

Comment: @Amy I am not seeing that - that body is directly from the request that fails, but maybe I am missing something, there are situations where that much json gets sent. Looking more.

Comment: @HungQuach The code that calls it is fine - it works locally, so the issue is somewhere on the backend.

Comment: @VSO The JSON you pasted into the question isn't congruent with the error path.  I am doubtful you have identified the errant content.

Comment: @Amy: Yea, I am inclined to agree - I am looking, ty for the help.

Comment: @VSO @Amy must be right about `Group_Is_Full` property in JSON. You missed actual request and posted here wrong JSON. Check it again.